# Redirect to a domain (Internal Panel) when logging in

Tags: apache, cross-domain, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm trying to make my website work this way ->

Main domain : www.mywebsite.com

Internal domain (logged user) : mypanel.com

The internal domain is not a subdomain, it is a new independent domain, what i want is instead the user redirect to www.mywebsite.com/panel it goes to www.mypanel.com, i did this setting the below config on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory  /var/www/html/panel>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
DocumentRoot  /var/www/html/panel/ 
ServerName mypanel.com
ServerAlias www.mypanel.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It works the way I want, except when user log in, it redirect to mypanel.com but then it redirect to logout (because of the session?) how could I make this work? Would I need to POST the session info and receive on the new domain?

Comment: You want two separate web sites to have a shared session data?

Comment: The website: www.mywebsite.com dont really need the session data, it will stop work when the user log in, and the mypanel.com will assume. Im trying to figure how to have the session stored with the new domain, and not the domain that is showing on the login page.

Comment: You cannot easily transfer file-stored session data between domain, especially if they are not on the same server. If they are, it's possible to pass the session key by URL, so the next domain can load the same session file, but that's risky thing to do.

Comment: @vuryss They're on the same server, what could be the risky in the situtation?

Comment: Transferring sensitive data in URL is a bad practice, cause there are multiple cases where someone uses that URL somewhere and they got his login.
The best thing to do in that case is to generate a token in the database after the login and use that token to redirect user to the next page. After the initial redirect, get the token, validate it, store what session data you need there and invalidate the token.

Comment: Thanks @vuryss, i will think about this...